# For a given X print numbers according to the scheme

Tags: python, python-3.x

> Write a function, which for a given h will print numbers according to the scheme:
> every line begins with a number 2^(line_number), then next natural numbers are added, so that in each line there were as many numbers as the line number.
> For example for `h` = 5 the expected output would be:
>
> ```
> 2
> 4,5
> 8,9,10
> 16,17,18,19
> 32,33,34,35,36
> ```

I was able only to do that:

```
def function():
    h = 1
    while h <= 5:
        a = 2**h
        h += 1
        print(a)
    return

function()
```

output:

```
2
4
8
16
32
```

It prints only the first numbers, no idea how to do it as required.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `range()` to create a sequence of numbers starting from `a` with the desired length, and print that as the row.

```
def function():
    for h in range(1, 6):
        a = 2**h
        row = range(a, a+h)
        print(",".join(str(num) for num in row))
```

Comment: Line 5, in function
    print(",".join(row))
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found

Comment: Sorry, added conversion to string.

Answer (score 0):

```
def func(val):
    h=2
    res = []
    for i in range(1, val+1):
        tmp =[h**i]
        tmp +=[tmp[0]+j for j in range(1, i)]
        
        res.append(tmp)
    return res
        
sol = func(5)
print(sol, sep='\n')
#[[2], [4, 5], [8, 9, 10], [16, 17, 18, 19], [32, 33, 34, 35, 36]]

print(*sol, sep='\n')
"""
[2]
[4, 5]
[8, 9, 10]
[16, 17, 18, 19]
[32, 33, 34, 35, 36]
"""
```

Comment: can you provide a little more explaination?